# Pass jQuery plugin as a argument to function.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for advice. What is the best method to pass jQuery plugin as a argument to function and execute it in context of DOM element. I want to do something like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.firstPlugin = function (options) {

    };
})(jQuery);


(function ($) {
    $.fn.secondPlugin = function (options) {

    };
})(jQuery);


function someFunction(argumentPlugin) {
    var someElement = document.getElementById("something");
    argumentPlugin.call(someElement); 
}

// what is better ?  
someFunction($.fn.firstPlugin);
// or
someFunction($.firstPlugin);
```

I would appreciate any ideas and tips.
Best regars.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to pass the plugin? Instead of this wouldn't it be easier to ensure that the plugin is in scope so that it can be used anywhere in your code.

Comment: what is not working with this code? tried: `argumentPlugin.call(null, someElement);`?

Comment: `someFunction($.fn.firstPlugin);` is preferred, because `$.firstPlugin` is supposed to be a static function and not actually plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you just passed in the name of the plugin

Say the name is `firstPlugin` and is used like this `$(element).firstPlugin();`

So just do ...

```
function someFunction(pluginName) {
    var someElement = document.getElementById("something");
    $(someElement)[pluginName](); 
}

someFunction('firstPlugin');
```

Comment: Your approach will not work if you pass non-jquery plugin but arbitrary function: `someFunction(function(element) { ... })`.

Comment: Isn't this question in relation to a jQuery plugin?

Comment: Why do you think so? `var someElement = document.getElementById("something");`. Plugin is just a piece of code, and you introduce tight coupling. It's nice to be able to write plugin in just javascript and use DI to execute it.

Comment: He said `Pass jQuery plugin ...` and wrote a jQuery plugin. Feel free to provide an answer. :)

Comment: @dcodesmith: provide an extra parameter to pass the plugin an optional  parameters object. It might be required at some point.

Answer (score 0):

$.firstPlugin will be undefined. 
$.fn is nothing but $.prototype so you cannot find the function reference in $.firstPlugin